# Can sql statement cause harddrive corruption?

Tags: sql, sqlite, database, hard-drive

Are there some **SQL** statements that are able to cause hard drive corruption faster? How large should the database tables be for the undesired effect to take an effect?

Which **SQL** statements should rather be avoided? I'm using **SQLite**. Is this worse in comparison to other **DMBS**?

This question sprang up because I'm often commiting these statements:

```
insert into t ...
update t set x = x + 1 where x >= some_value
```

What if one day the number of rows will be 50000? Is this still safe for the hard drive?

I tried to show an example to illustrate the background but conceive the main question as:

> Which **SQL** statements (on how large data) should rather be avoided?

Comment: If you want to reduce the number of writes, then do it for better performance (to make it faster). A proper hard drive will be able to perform all the writes you need to update your 50000 records.

Comment: To those of you down-voting this question: Why? It is a perfectly valid question. Just that most will know the answer does not make the question bad!

Comment: I feel quite bad that I'm a black sheep and most people know it :-) but I really wasn't sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a hard drive wants to live, it will live. If it wants to die, it will die.

Anyway, hear Google: Failure Trends in a Large Disk Drive Population

http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/en//archive/disk_failures.pdf

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive#Metrics_of_failures

If you are afraid (or not) of data loss, you should consider using backups, replications, whatever. Valuable data should be preserved at least two different places.

Answer (score 2):

> *Are there some SQL statements that are able to cause hard drive corruption faster?*

No.

And definitely not something like the number "*50000*".

For the harddisk it makes not difference whether it's a DBMS reading or writing or some other program.

Answer (score 2):

On HDDs unless you have power saving turned on so that the spindle isn't running when you aren't executing a query then it won't make any real difference.

SSDs are more interesting. Try to avoid writes, large writes don't matter too much but lots of  regular small writes could cause cell death. However this should be implemented at the OS tier not the DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its completely save.

Our application on daily basis insert around

```
-----------
 245091
 (1 row(s) affected)
```

Where all these values are inserted in one table.
Hence you don't need to worry. What you need to keep an eye is on you log file. Which get completely filled.

You need to truncate that. Depending how much size you would like to give on your hard disk.

Comment: The `(1 row(s) affected)` is slightly contradictory to your answer :-)

Comment: Actually i wrote

select COUNT(*) from Report1
where date='11-03-2012'

Which gave me this respond.
Nice catch by the way :)